# Build historical tracking of changes to a row base on information in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have an table consisting of all items within our company - the Item table.
Each row represents one item with the newest values for each attribute (e.g. unit price, profit for this item, vendor, description and so forth. )
Ex.:

```
ItemNo | Description | Unit Price | Profit % |
----------------------------------------------
1      |  MyItem     |   200      |   47     |
2      | MyOtherItem |   300      |   25     |
```

In another table I have historical changes for the Item-table - the ChangeLog History Table
It shows the ItemNo, The column the has been changed, the old and the new value and a DateCreated-column showing when the change happened. Like this:

```
ItemNo | ColumnName  | OldValue | New Value | DateCreated |
-----------------------------------------------------------
1      |  Unit Price |    50    |   100     | 20170401    |
1      |  Unit Price |    100   |   200     | 20170501    |
2      |  Profit %   |     2    |    25     | 20170603    |
1      |  Profit %   |     99   |    47     | 20170604    |
```

I want to create a table that looks like the Item table, but where all changes are tracked chronologically based on the Changelog Hisotry Table, with a ValidFrom and ValidTo Date. So the Item-table in the beginning should look like this:

```
ItemNo | Description | Unit Price | Profit % | ValidFrom  | ValidTo
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1      |  MyItem     |   200      |   47     | 2017-06-04 | 9999-12-31
1      |  MyItem     |   200      |   99     | 2017-05-01 | 2017-06-04
1      |  MyItem     |   100      |   99     | 2017-04-01 | 2017-05-01
1      |  MyItem     |   50       |   99     | 1900-01-01 | 2017-04-01
2      | MyOtherItem |   300      |   25     | 2017-06-03 | 9999-12-31
2      | MyOtherItem |   300      |   2      | 1900-01-01 | 2017-06-03
```

So the question is how do I create that with T-SQL? I alsp have SSIS at my disposal but I have no idea how to fix this, Been trying to get my head around it for hours now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's possible in SSIS. You need to create a `lookup task` to read changes. If change is found, a logic(update statement) will be there to update current ValidTo and insert statement to insert new row.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Prabhat. But what will the lookup value be? The Column names are in the "ColumnName" column. How do tell SSIS what column to change the value in, and how should the logic be constructed?

Comment: @BennyChristiansen how many columns you need to check, when you have update? The main problem is column changes detection. Suppose in one day you have 2 different column updates for the same row, what do you expect in this case? Can you have only 1 string with all attributes in the history table with effective versioning?

Comment: If two updates are happening at the same day, there will  be two new rows in the Changelog table: Two column names added to "ColumnNames" column and two values en both "OldValue" and "NewValue" and two dates in "DateCreated" which are the same. In my Item table i would like to show this as only one row (meaning one update for that row, for that day, where two values changed)

Comment: @BennyChristiansen if you will change Unit Price twice for ItemNo = 1 during the day, in Item-table you need only the last modified value?

Comment: There will not be to changes in one day to same column (workflow constraints),so yeah :)

Comment: @BennyChristiansen check my answer please. Is I really understand your question or not.

Comment: What are the data types? For example, when the `Description` is updated how will you store it in `OldValue` if `OldValue` is an `INT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, for 2 columns:

```
WITH hist AS (
  -- sample change log data
  select * 
  from (
    Values
         (1,'Unit Price',50 ,100, cast('20170401' as date))
        ,(1,'Unit Price',100,200,'20170501')
        ,(2,'Profit %', 2 , 25,'20170603')
        ,(1,'Profit %', 99, 47,'20170604') 
    ) t(ItemNo,ColumnName,OldValue,NewValue,DateCreated )
),
items AS(
  -- sample items data
  select * 
  from (
    Values
         (1, 'MyItem',211,4)
        ,(2,'MyOtherItem',311,2)
     ) t(ItemNo,Description,UnitPrice,[Profit %])
),
-- Solution
hist2 AS (
    -- Add the very old values from change log as new starting at 1900-01-01
    SELECT * 
    FROM hist
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES ItemNo, ColumnName, null, OldValue, '19000101'
    FROM hist
    ORDER BY row_number() over (partition by ItemNo, ColumnName order by DateCreated)   
),    
intv AS (
    -- Get itervals from augmented change log
    SELECT ItemNo
      , sD = DateCreated
      , eD = coalesce(dateadd(day, -1, lead(DateCreated) over (partition by ItemNo order by DateCreated)),'99991231')
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ItemNo, DateCreated 
        FROM hist2
    ) t
)
-- Fill intervals with values from augmented change log, using Items values as a last resort
SELECT items.ItemNo, items.Description, Sd, Ed
  , coalesce(p1.UnitPrice, items.UnitPrice)
  , coalesce(p2.[Profit %], items.[Profit %])
FROM intv
OUTER APPLY (
    select top(1) UnitPrice = NewValue
    from hist2 h
    where h.ItemNo = intv.ItemNo and h.ColumnName = 'Unit Price' and DateCreated <= Ed
    order by DateCreated desc
    ) p1
OUTER APPLY (
    select top(1) [Profit %] = NewValue
    from hist2  h
    where h.ItemNo = intv.ItemNo and h.ColumnName = 'Profit %' and DateCreated <= Ed
    order by DateCreated desc
    ) p2 
JOIN items ON items.ItemNo = intv.ItemNo
```

You may want to instantiate hist2 and add proper indices for better perfomance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a recursive CTE like below

For convenience I've create table variables to store the input data. You don't need these, and should replace the variable mentions later on with the correct table names

```
declare @item table (ItemNo int, Description varchar(100), [Unit Price] decimal(10,4), [Profit %] decimal(10,4))
insert into @item values
(1,'MyItem',200,47),
(2,'MyOtherItem',  300 ,25)


declare @itemhistory table (ItemNo int,ColumnName varchar(100),OldValue varchar(100),NewValue varchar(100),DateCreated varchar(100))
insert into @itemhistory values
(1,'Unit Price', '50' ,'100','20170401'),
(1,'Unit Price', '100','200','20170501'),
(2,'Profit %',  '2' ,  '25', '20170603'),
(1,'Profit %',  '99' , '47', '20170604')
```

This is step #1 . We create a history temp table which allows us to form two date range pairs

```
declare @history table (ItemNo int,ColumnName varchar(100),OldValue varchar(100),NewValue varchar(100),DateCreated varchar(100),validFrom varchar(100))
insert into @history
select 
    i1.*,
     isnull(max(i2.DateCreated),'19000101') validFrom 
from @itemHistory i1
left join @itemHistory i2
    on i1.DateCreated>i2.DateCreated and i1.ItemNo=i2.ItemNo
group by i1.ColumnName,i1.OldValue,i1.NewValue,i1.DateCreated,i1.ItemNo
```

Here's the recursive CTE which will use @history date range

```
;with cte as 
(
select 
    i.ItemNo,
    i.description,
    i.[Unit Price],
    i.[Profit %], 
    cast(h.validfrom as date) as ValidFrom,
    CAST (N'9999-12-31'as date) as ValidTo
from @item i outer apply 
    (
        select 
            max(DateCreated) validfrom 
        from @history 
        where i.ItemNo=ItemNo 
        and cast(DateCreated  as date) <CAST (N'9999-12-31'as date)
    )h

union all

select 
    c.ItemNo,
    c.description,
    case when h.ColumnName ='Unit Price' then h.OldValue else c.[Unit Price] end as [Unit Price],
    case when h.ColumnName ='Profit %' then h.OldValue else c.[Profit %] end as [Profit %],
    h.validFrom as ValidFrom,
    c.ValidFrom ValidTo
from cte c outer apply
    (
    select 
        DateCreated validTo,
        cast(validFrom as date) validFrom,
        ColumnName,
        OldValue
    from @history
    where c.ItemNo=ItemNo
    and cast(DateCreated as date) = c.ValidFrom 
    and case 
        when  ColumnName ='Unit Price' then c.[Unit Price] 
        when ColumnName ='Profit %' then c.[Profit %]
        end = NewValue

    )h 
where NOT c.Validfrom ='1900-01-01'

)
select * from cte order by ItemNO asc, ValidFrom desc
```

This is the output

```
--Output
--ItemNo | Description | Unit Price | Profit % | ValidFrom  | ValidTo
--1      |  MyItem     |   200      |   47     | 2017-06-04 | 9999-12-31
--1      |  MyItem     |   200      |   99     | 2017-05-01 | 2017-06-04
--1      |  MyItem     |   100      |   99     | 2017-04-01 | 2017-05-01
--1      |  MyItem     |   50       |   99     | 1900-01-01 | 2017-04-01
--2      | MyOtherItem |   300      |   25     | 2017-06-03 | 9999-12-31
--2      | MyOtherItem |   300      |   2      | 1900-01-01 | 2017-06-03
```

Comment: Thanls for the suggestion, but i couldn't make it work after how I wanted. I only got two rows for each item no matter how many updates there were.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I do the same task on my current job place for last 4 month,
we named it "effective versioning". If I really understand what do you want,
try to do next steps. I do not use your second table, maby you need it to make something like audit.

```
use db_test; --your DB name
set dateformat dmy;
go
--your first table
if object_id('dbo.item_table') is not null
drop table dbo.item_table;

create table dbo.item_table
(
    [ItemNo]        int,
    [Description]   varchar(max),
    [Unit Price]    numeric(18, 2),
    [Profit %]      numeric(4, 2)
);

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--your second table --but I dont use it
if object_id('dbo.item_column_hist') is not null
drop table dbo.item_column_hist;

create table dbo.item_column_hist
(
    [ItemNo]            int,
    [ColumnName]        varchar(max),
    [OldValue]          varchar(max),
    [New Value]         varchar(max),
    [DateCreated]       date
);
go
create trigger item_column_change
on dbo.item_table
after update as
begin
    if update([Unit Price]) 
        begin
            insert into dbo.item_column_hist
            select 
                i.ItemNo,
                'Unit Price',
                d.[Unit Price],
                i.[Unit Price],
                cast(getdate() as date)
            from 
                inserted i join deleted d
                    on i.ItemNo = d.ItemNo
         end
    if update([Profit %])
        begin
            insert into dbo.item_column_hist
            select 
                i.ItemNo,
                'Profit %',
                d.[Profit %],
                i.[Profit %],
                cast(getdate() as date)
            from 
                inserted i join deleted d
                    on i.ItemNo = d.ItemNo
        end
end;
go
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--your third table
if object_id('dbo.item_raw_hist') is not null
drop table dbo.item_raw_hist;

create table dbo.item_raw_hist
(
    [ItemNo]            int,
    [Description]       varchar(max),
    [Unit Price]        numeric(18, 2),
    [Profit %]          numeric(4, 2),
    [ValidFrom]         date,
    [ValidTo]           date
);
go
create trigger item_raw_hist_insert
on dbo.item_table
after insert as
begin
    insert into dbo.item_raw_hist
    select a.*, 
        cast('01-01-1900' as date),
        cast('31-12-9999' as date) 
    from inserted a
end;

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
go
create trigger item_raw_hist_update
on dbo.item_table
after update as
begin
    with cte as (select * from dbo.item_raw_hist where itemNo in (select itemNo from deleted))
    merge into cte as target
    using inserted as source
        on target.itemNo = source.itemNo
        and target.[validTo] = cast('31-12-9999' as date) 
        and target.[Unit Price] = source.[Unit Price]
        and target.[Profit %] = source.[Profit %]
    when not matched by source
    then
        update set target.[validTo] = cast(getdate() as date)
    when not matched by target
    then
        insert (
             [ItemNo]       
            ,[Description]  
            ,[Unit Price]   
            ,[Profit %]     
            ,[ValidFrom]        
            ,[ValidTo]      
        ) values (
             source.[ItemNo]        
            ,source.[Description]   
            ,source.[Unit Price]    
            ,source.[Profit %]
            ,cast(getdate() as date)
            ,cast('31-12-9999' as date)         
        );
end;
```

Assuming that the record does not really change more than once a day, according to your business processes, the code should work stably. **But in fact it will work an all cases, only the difference is, that can be more then 1 row for one day in last table for the same ItemNo.**

```
--AN EXAMPLE
select * from dbo.item_table;
select * from dbo.item_column_hist;
select * from dbo.item_raw_hist;

insert into dbo.item_table 
values 
    (1, 'MyItem', 200, 47), 
    (2, 'MyOtherItem', 300, 25);

update dbo.item_table
set [Unit Price] = 400
where itemno = 1;


select * from dbo.item_table;
select * from dbo.item_column_hist;
select * from dbo.item_raw_hist;
```

Hope it will help you with your routine process automatization.